# How do I "select back until the first non-whitespace character" in TextMate 1.5?

Tags: textmate

Following [a nice advice](http://blog.peterhaza.no/textmate-tip-go-to-first-non-space-character-on-current-line/), I was able to create a macro to "go to the first non-whitespace character" in TextMate 1.5.

Now I'd like to improve it further, in order to "select back from current point up until the first non-whitespace character", i.e. in this line if the cursor was just after the "§" here, it would select: `Now I'd like to improve it further, in order to "select back from current point up until the first non-whitespace character", i.e. in this line if the cursor was just after the "§`

The trick used in that advice doesn't help here, since once you "search" for the first non-whitespace character, you lose the selection. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TextMate 2 then you can enable indent-aware movement, selection, and deletion.

For more info see https://github.com/textmate/textmate/wiki/Hidden-Settings#keybindings

Comment: I'll reconsider switching, thanks. Meanwhile I'll update the question. (meanwhile don't delete this answer anyway!)